# How to convert tuple to int?

Tags: python, string

This is the code I am trying to run :

```
line = "123456789"
p = 2
print line[p,p+2]
```

And I get the error - `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not tuple`. How can I use line[ , ] with variables. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably meant `line[p:p+2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use colons for slicing.

```
line = "123456789"
p = 2
print line[p:p+2]
```

That works fine.

Output:

```
34
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line = "123456789"
p = 2
print line[p,p+2] # this is incorrect slice notation
```

the correct form is:

```
print line[p:p+2] # with a colon
```

look [here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/strings.html) for info on strings and string slicing